# Xcode: Temporarily disable indexing/auto-compilation?

Tags: xcode, macos

Judging just from the amount of heat given off by the laptop, the auto-indexing feature of Xcode is very CPU-intensive. It very often spikes way above 100% on Activity Monitor, so it's clearly doing some things in parallel as well. I'd like to do some C++/ObjC programming on the go, but the battery won't last very long if the CPU is being thrashed like this.

Is there a mode I can throw it into so that it will be less aggressive about this? If I disable it, I want to also be able to re-enable it easily when I do get plugged in.

As it is now i'd prefer to use Sublime Text (with e.g. `xcodebuild` manual compilation feedback) to do the editing in an all-day work situation because the text buffers are GPU-accelerated in that app, which helps to keep things cool.

Comment: I definitely run Xcode on my laptop and the major indexing really only happens once. After that it should be pretty low CPU. Are you using the latest Xcode?

Comment: @nielsbot Yeah, you do make a good point. However even the auto-compilation and other clang based niceties can be temporarily done without to make Xcode much less resource intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> General, and disable "Show live issues" from the Issues option.

Comment: Sorry, I have to unaccept this because even though it stops the display of the auto-analysis, it does not appear to improve the CPU hit that Xcode causes, and I will always prefer to see all available data if it is computed. Effectively it is still doing all the work, and having a checkbox to disable the UI display of this is of no use to me. Unfortunately I think this question has no true answer because there are probably architectural aspects of the IDE itself that make the CPU drain inescapable. (Watch it while you scroll a buffer, for example -- then try this in e.g. Sublime Text)